# Comma vs. em-dash

Tags: commas, dashes

When is it appropriate to use em dashes instead of commas?  I have tried commas in this sentence, but it seems too disjointed:

> I'm going to be here at Zep, just up the road from KO near Howell Mill, for a few more weeks, and thought you and Kelly might like to meet somewhere for lunch one day.

Comment: I don't have any trouble understanding your original version or the versions with parentheses or em dashes suggested by Dancrumb and Joe Dark below. That being the case, I advise you to let your own preference be your guide.

Comment: I was given some advice long ago about convoluted writing with lots of non-essential clauses: "It doesn't matter if you use commas, parentheses, or dashes to set off a non-essential clause. Whatever you use, it's a non-essential clause. Since it's not essential to what you are writing, why did you write it?" The advice was rather solid, but for some reason my convoluted mind refuses to obey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, em dashes are more appropriate. Em dashes are commonly used as alternatives to parentheses and the location of Zep is definitely parenthetical to the rest of this sentence.

Thus, suitable alternatives might be:

> I'm going to be here at Zep (just up the road from KO near Howell Mill) for a few more weeks, and thought you and Kelly might like to meet somewhere for lunch one day.

or

> I'm going to be here at Zep—just up the road from KO near Howell Mill—for a few more weeks, and thought you and Kelly might like to meet somewhere for lunch one day.

Personally, I think the em dashes are overkill here; they highlight the parenthetical clause in a way that I don't think is truly necessary, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

The **em dash** has several uses. It allows, in a manner similar to parentheses, an additional thought to be added within a sentence by sort of breaking away from that ***sentence—as I’ve done here.***

```
 Its use or misuse for this purpose is a matter of taste, and subject to the effect   
 on the writer’s or reader’s “ear.”
```

Comma consistency appeals to me as a reader in the original post:

> I'm going to be here at Zep, just up the road from KO near Howell Mill, for a few more weeks, and thought you and Kelly might like to meet somewhere for lunch one day.

Some readers may find @Dancrumb or @Joe Dark's version better:

> I'm going to be here at Zep—just up the road from KO near Howell Mill—for a few more weeks, and thought you and Kelly might like to meet somewhere for lunch one day.

```
 This explanation is not intended to be exhaustive (see chapter 6 in CMOS 16).
```

**Em dash or comma: being *consistent* is the bottomline.**

Answer (score 1):

**I’m going to be here at Zep (just up the road from KO near Howell Mill) for a few more weeks and thought you and Kelly might like to meet somewhere for lunch one day.**

This is how I would write the sentence. Dashes can also be used as parentheses but I believe brackets are neater and more readily understood as containing additional information within a sentence.

No commas before or after the brackets because the additional info does not separate clauses.
No comma after Zep because the sentence without the additional info wouldn't use one.
No comma between; ***'weeks and'*** because ***thought you and Kelly...*** etc, wouldn't be a complete sentence on its own.